# Django: How do i extract the email ID of users on the admin page

Tags: python, mysql, django

How do I extract the email ID of users from the Users columns? I've managed to make sure that the name of the users are extracted through the Users table.

```
class Project(models.Model):
   STATUS_CHOICE = (
       ('Project Manager', 'Project Manager'),
       ('Technician', 'Technician'),
       ('Tester', 'Tester')
   )
   STATUS_CHOICE_1 = (
       ('Work Assigned', 'Work Assigned'),
       ('Work in Progress', 'Work in Progress'),
       ('Testing', 'Testing'),
       ('Completed', 'Completed')
   )
   project_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   project_description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   Admin_Name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   Admin_Mail_ID = models.EmailField(max_length=50)
   Project_Manager_1 = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="Project_Manager_1_users")
   Project_Manager_1_Mail_ID = models.EmailField(max_length=50)
   Project_Manager_2 = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
   Project_Manager_2_Mail_ID = models.EmailField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
   Technician_1 = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="Technician_1_users")
   Technician_1_Mail_ID = models.EmailField(max_length=50)
   Technician_2 = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
   Technician_2_Mail_ID = models.EmailField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
   Technician_3 = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
   Technician_3_Mail_ID = models.EmailField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
   Tester_1 = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
   Tester_1_Mail_ID = models.EmailField(max_length=50, default='Example@gmail.com')
   Additional_User_1 = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
   Additional_User_1_Type = models.CharField(max_length=18, choices=STATUS_CHOICE, blank=True, null=True)
   Additional_User_1_Mail_ID = models.EmailField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
   Additional_User_2 = models.CharField(max_length=18, blank=True, null=True)
   Additional_User_2_Type = models.CharField(max_length=18, choices=STATUS_CHOICE, blank=True, null=True)
   Additional_User_2_Mail_ID = models.EmailField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
   Additional_User_3 = models.CharField(max_length=18, blank=True, null=True)
   Additional_User_3_Type = models.CharField(max_length=18, choices=STATUS_CHOICE, blank=True, null=True)
   Additional_User_3_Mail_ID = models.EmailField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
   Status_of_the_project = models.CharField(max_length=18, choices=STATUS_CHOICE_1)
   Created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)
   Finish_Date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
   Supporting_Documents = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True)
```

I'm not that great at coding and I would really appreciate all the help I'd get.. Thank you so much everyone..

Comment: What do you mean by 'email ID'? right now you are connecting user objects as foreign keys and those contain every information about the user connected.
Perhaps are you referring to the pk, primary key, of the user?

Comment: What I mean is, every user is associated with a specific email ID, right? That email ID, I want it to be autofilled when the user's name is entered in the users Names column so that there is no need to switch pages to check and figure up what the persons email ID is

Comment: why are you duplicating information in the database? you should only store which users are part of your project, then you can fetch all information needed when you need it. E.g. if `project` is a `Project` instance, `project.project_manager_1.email` gives you the email without having to save it in an `EmailField` in the `Project` model. You don't need `Project_Manager_1_Mail_ID` field.

Comment: Also your model is terribly inflexible, because if one day you need to add a 4th technician, you can't without changing your model. You should think of creating a `Role` model and adding users via the `Role` to the `Project`. Look at `ManyToMany` and `through` relationships in the [Django documentation on models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships)